# how to automatically delete created file in linux with inotify?

Tags: linux, inotify

I am trying to delete a created file with inotify but it doesn't work:

```
inotifywait -r --format '%w%f' -e create /test && rm $FILE
```

when i create a file in /test I get this:

```
/test/somefile.txt
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

so it seems that the $FILE variable is not passed to the rm command... how can I do this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I hope you don't do that to get temporary files! To get a temporary file, just `unlink` the entry in its directory while still having an `open`-ed file descriptor... which is what `tmpfile` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When launching your inotifywait once (without the -m flag), you can easily use [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) :

```
inotifywait -r --format '%w%f' -e create /test -q | xargs /bin/rm
```

that will wait for a file creation in /test, give the filename to xargs and give this arg to `/bin/rm` to delete the file, then it will exit.

If you need to continuously watch your directory (with the -m param of inotifywait), create a script file like this :

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create /test | while read FILE
do
        /bin/rm $FILE
done
```

And then, every newly file created in you /test directory will be removed.